# Form submit only after modal validation

Tags: html, forms, laravel-5.5

I'm using [this package](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html) to create my forms.
And I'm currently using this code to confirm the suppresion of an item

```
{!! Form::open( ['method' => 'delete', 'url' => route($entity.'.destroy', [$entity => $id]), 'style' => 'display: inline', 'onSubmit' => 'confirm("Do you really want to delete that?")']) !!}
    <button type="submit" class="btn-delete btn btn-xs btn-danger">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
    </button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

This works fine but I would like to replace this ugly js confirm by a modal

So I tried this

```
{!! Form::open( ['method' => 'delete', 'url' => route($entity.'.destroy', [$entity => $id]), 'style' => 'display: inline', 'onSubmit' => '$("#modal_' . $id. '").modal("show");']) !!}
    <button type="submit" class="btn-delete btn btn-xs btn-danger">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
    </button>
{!! Form::close() !!}


<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modal_{{ $id }}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
        <div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <p>You are about to delete.</p>
                    <p>Do you want to proceed?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>                 
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span> Confirm
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the item is deleted before any click on the modal.

Is it possible to trigger the modal properly by using this package or should I just go by writing my old school html form ?

Comment: Why not have the form go nowhere, and just have an onclick, which triggers your modal, and when that modal confirms it, use AJAX to post to the real delete form?

Comment: @zack6849 It could be a solution but I'm asking if this kind of feature is possible with the `laravelcollective/html` ... otherwise I'll obiously go for the AJAX solution !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the Form package is to just help you create html form elements. Changing the package for a plain html form would end up with the same results, because all it does is generate the same elements tags that are written with html with the help of PHP.

Changing the first button to trigger the modal, and using the modal confirm button to submit the form would work.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_{{ $id }}">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modal_{{ $id }}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
        <div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <p>You are about to delete.</p>
                    <p>Do you want to proceed?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>                 
                    {!! Form::open( ['method' => 'delete', 'url' => route($entity . '.destroy', [$entity => $id]) ]) !!}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn-delete btn btn-xs btn-danger">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                        </button>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```